# FBSDK swift 3 with 53 errors

Tags: ios, swift, facebook

I'm trying to download Facebook's sdk on Cocoapods following the instructions in the README 
https://github.com/facebook/facebook-sdk-swift

I downloaded Cocoapods, inserted

```
pod 'FacebookCore'
pod 'FacebookLogin'
pod 'FacebookShare'
```

into my Podfile, executed pod install and opened my xcworkspace. But when I run my app I get 53 error messages like

```
"Function types cannot have argument label 'bytesSent'; use'_' instead"
```

[image]

I could try manually fixing these errors but is this supposed to happen?

I'm using Swift 3

Answer (score 1):

Try clean and re-build the project or refactor it to the newest Swift syntax again. This seems to be a bug in the newest Xcode release (I exprerienced it in the previous version though).